# How to import obj in Blender 4.0 with python?

Tags: python, import, obj

I used to use `bpy.ops.import_scene.obj()` in my addon.
which can import .obj object and set it a selected object.(not active)

But in Blender 4.0. this does not work any more.

I know the code `bpy.ops.wm.obj_import()` does the similar thing. but this code import an obj and set it active which I do not wish.

So I want to know what is the `bpy.ops.import_scene.obj()` in Blender 4.0, or is there a way to change the `bpy.ops.wm.obj_import()` code not import an obj in active mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the operator side, I don't think there is a way to get the behavior of the old operator using the new operator which replaces the old one in Blender 4.0. However, I think it's relatively easy to save the active object before running the operator, and restore it after it finishes.

Something like this:

```
active_object = bpy.context.active_object
# Run bpy.ops.wm.obj_import()
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = active_object
```

Comment: Thank you!It works! Best!!!